# Recording voice and playing it with naudio

Tags: c#, record, naudio

there is a problem with recording i cant play it.players says this item's file format may be unsupported.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recorder = new WaveIn();
        recorder.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
        recorder.StartRecording();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filewriter = new WaveFileWriter("C:\\Users\\oguzhan\\ödev\\deneme.wav", recorder.WaveFormat);
        recorder.StopRecording();
        WaveStream mainOutputStream = new WaveFileReader("C:\\Users\\oguzhan\\ödev\\deneme.wav");
        WaveChannel32 volumeStream = new WaveChannel32(mainOutputStream);
        player = new WaveOut();
        player.Init(volumeStream);
        player.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it at the moment you create the `WaveFileWriter` object, stop recording, then write nothing to the wav file.  What you end up with is an empty file that will not be even slightly useful.

Create the `WaveFileWriter` first, before you start the recording.  In the `DataAvailable` event handler for your `recorder` object write the received sample data to the `WaveFileWriter`.  Then when you are done with the recording, dispose of the `WaveFileWriter` to finalize it.

Once you have done that you should have a valid wav file.